# Why I can't align two buttons

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have problem, I can't align two buttons in one line.

I tried to set padding of span class pptext2 but without success.
Here is code
http://jsfiddle.net/71782p4L/1/

HTML

```
<div class="ppdiv">
<button class="ppenvelope"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RfLMyak.jpg" alt="Slika"></button><button class="pptext"><span class="pptext2">PRIVATE MESSAGE</span></button>
</div><!--Zatvoren ppdiv-->
```

CSS

```
.ppdiv{
    padding-top:22px;
    padding-left: 19px;

}
.ppdiv img{
    padding:10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.ppenvelope{
    border:none;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
   background: #b2d4dd;
}
.pptext{
    border:none;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
       background: #c9e0e6;
}
.pptext2{
    display: inline-block;
     color:#4c6974;
       padding-top: 15px;
       padding-bottom:13px;
       padding-left: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set `float: left;` on both buttons and `overflow: hidden;` on `.ppdiv`. To make sure both buttons stay the same height, also set `height` on them (e.g. `height: 48px;`). You can also remove the `span.pptext2` element altogether, unless you need it for other purposes. Take a look at the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/igi33/ck4w6cLq/1/.

HTML:

```
<div class="ppdiv">
    <button class="ppenvelope">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RfLMyak.jpg" alt="Slika">
    </button>
    <button class="pptext">PRIVATE MESSAGE</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ppdiv{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ppenvelope, .pptext {
    float: left;
    border: none;
    height: 48px;
}
.ppenvelope{
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    background: #b2d4dd;
}
.ppdiv img{
    padding:10px;
}
.pptext{
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    background: #c9e0e6;
    color:#4c6974;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `vertical-align: middle;` on both buttons.

```
.pptext {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #c9e0e6;
  border: medium none;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.ppenvelope {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #b2d4dd;
  border: medium none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I just changed to answer to vertical align middle on both buttons! did you try that  ?

Comment: Thats it, but I had to change padding-top: 13.7px;
    padding-bottom:12.1px; 
Is this ok this measurements 12.1 and 13.7 , with thats padding its ok

Comment: this is not good, on 100% screen, if I zoom looks better.http://i.imgur.com/vKyDtzF.png

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/71782p4L/2/

Here you are.

```
.ppdiv {
    height:43px; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
.ppdiv img {
    padding:10px;
}
.ppenvelope {
    border:none;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    background: #b2d4dd;
    float:left;
    height:100%; /*Sets height to 100% of current container, of which is ppdiv (43px) */
}
.pptext {
    border:none;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    background: #c9e0e6;
        height:100%; /*Sets height to 100% of current container, of which is ppdiv (43px)*/
}
```